# jsp:include tag doesn't work in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, jspinclude

when i click a button i need to go from one jsp to another.
my code is below,

```
<html>
<hedd>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function go() {
        document.myForm.txt1.value= "helloooo" ; 
           <jsp:include page="Slip18-1.jsp" >
              <jsp:param name="param1" value="value1"/>
           </jsp:include>
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <form name="myForm">
      enter range<input type="text" name="txt1" value="aaaaa" />
                 <input type="text" name="txt2" />
      <% out.println(" <input type=\"button\" value=\"submit\" onclick=\"go()\"> "); %>
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Slip18-1.jsp is also in the same directory.
If i remove jsp:include tag from javascript it will print "hello" in textbox field.
if i put jsp:include tag in , that is outside script then also it will work!
How can i solve this?

Comment: Of course not because JSP tags run on the server and Javascript runs on the client. Your JSP includes are simply printing out those pages before sending the HTML to the browser.

Comment: but i have heard that we can use jsp tags in javascript. And if it is not possible then how can i put include tag in button click?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is to print a location into your javascript (before its sent to the client), and use javascript to change the address:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function go() 
   {
      document.myForm.txt1.value= "helloooo" ; 
      document.location.href = "Slip18-1.jsp?param1=<%=value1%>";
   }
 </script>
```

If not, then lookup Ajax.  For instance, you could use [jquery](http://jquery.com/)'s Ajax method to send a request to Slip18-1.jsp and then do something with the response:

```
         $.ajax({
             type : "POST",
             url : "Slip18-1.jsp",
             data : {
                 'param1' : '<%=value1%>'
             },
             success : function(data)
             {
                alert(data);
                 $("#someHTMLElementID").html(data); //put the response in an element with id='someHTMLElementID', example <div id='someHTMLElementID'></div>
             }
         });
```